# How to enable shutdown option on windows 2003 server login screen?

Tags: windows-server-2003

How can I enable the immediate shutdown without logging in on the windows 2003 server login screen.

I know it is less secure because anyone can shut the machine down then.

(But "they" could always pull the power plug anyway ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Computer Configuration / Windows Settings / Security Settings / Local Policies / Security Options.

Entry: "Shutdown: Allow system to be shut down without having to log on". Double click on it, change it to "Enabled".

(I think, obviously the end goal is getting to Security Options, I don't have a WS03 machine in front of me.)